# Javascript "window": What is its purpose? What does it do?

Tags: javascript, browser

I know this may sound basic, but bear with me. I'm curious about the low-level functionality and intentions of the window object.

What is the purpose of the javascript window object? What is its core functionality? I know that everything is stored in the window in browsers. SpiderMonkey(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla#SpiderMonkey) doesn't have window defined by default, so it must be a browser object.

What is its purpose?

Comment: something has to be at the end of the road... window is a browser thing, but almost all runtimes provide a similar alias for the global object.

Comment: Someone should do a good 2-liner for this question.

Comment: why the browser tools (open(), prompt(), etc) can't live off of window.browser or an existing name like navigator is a historical question. considering the rush of the early web, it very well might not have originally had a flawless design and plan.

Comment: ECMAScript has a [*global object*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1) associated with the global execution context. In browsers, there is a host [*window object*](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/) (also see [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window)) that is effectively an alias for the global object and has additional host methods and properties. Other implemenations (other than browsers) may implement *window* too, or some other alias for the global object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window is the global scope in any browser application.  Your code is run from the window.  When you open up the javascript console in your browser and start coding, you're working from the window scope.  That being said, this is just the tip of the iceberg known as closure scope.  Each function you invoke will have it's own closure (closure is just a fancy word for the environment in which a functions code runs).  Two functions invoked from the window will not have access to each others closure, however they will have access to their parent scopes, in this case, the window.  Example:

```
var x = 'hello'   // saves 'hello' as variable x in window/ global scope
var greeting = function(){
    console.log(x);
    var y = ' world';  // stores ' world' as y in greeting closure scope
}

var toGreet = function(){
    console.log(y);
}

greeting();   // logs 'Hello', stores ' world' as variable y in greeting closure scope
toGreet();    // Errors, because y is undefined.  toGreet does not have access to greetings closure scope
```

If you have variables or constants (or any value, for that matter) that you want to be shared across scope, you could define that variable in the window-- then you can access those values from any function.  Like this!

var x = 'hello'
var y = 'world'

```
var greeting = function(){
    console.log(x);
}

var toGreet = function(){
    console.log(y);
}

greeting();   // logs 'Hello'
toGreet();    // logs ' world'
```

Unfortunately, the concept of scope goes much deeper than this, but this should give you a good idea of what the window is...  And just an aside:  usually it's in your best interest not to keep variables in the window because you might accidentally alter them in one function, but need them in another.  The best way to share variables across functions is by passing it in as a parameter to the function.

If you want more about scope and closures, check out [this blog](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/)!

Comment: I understand what scope is. So basically, it's just a scope for the browser to work within?

Comment: Oh, awesome.  Yeah, you could look at it that way.  The window is just the overarching scope that your entire program runs from.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing client side programming for a web page, the `window` object is an special object that also happens to be the global scope of JavaScript execution.

- Need to access the HTML DOM? Use `window.document`.
- Need to know the current URL or want to navigate back and forth? Use `window.location`, and `window.history`.
- Need to know the information about the web browser being used? Use `window.navigator`
- etc...

Likewise, there is a plethora of properties, methods, events, and objects you can access through the `window` object. Here are some references:

- Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window
- W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp
- MSIE Dev Center: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535873(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javawindow.html

Comment: you can view them all for a given browser using Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window); even on about:blank, window has 500+ properties defined in chrome and firefox, 300+ in IE 10. a few dozen of these are actually useful for making apps.

Comment: `"it is essential to have access to the page you are trying to program with JavaScript. The window object is there for that"`. Not really, the "page" is represented by a *document* object (*cf* DOM), which is quite different to *window*.

Comment: @RobG: Noted with thanks. I wrote the answer to be helpful for a newbie JavaScript programmer. I've since updated the answer.